# Extend numerical series in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, range, numeric

**Data**
Let's take a look at a simple dataset (mine is actually >200,000 rows):

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep(1, 11), rep(2,6)),
  ref.pos = c(NA,NA,NA,301,302,303,800,801,NA,NA,NA, 500,501,502, NA, NA, NA),
  pos     = c(1:11, 30:35)
)
```

Which thus looks like this:

```
   id ref.pos pos
1   1      NA   1
2   1      NA   2
3   1      NA   3
4   1     301   4
5   1     302   5
6   1     303   6
7   1     800   7
8   1     801   8
9   1      NA   9
10  1      NA  10
11  1      NA  11
12  2     500  30
13  2     501  31
14  2     502  32
15  2      NA  33
16  2      NA  34
17  2      NA  35
```

**What I want to achieve**
Per `id` I want to extend the numbers in the `ref.pos` to fill out the whole column, where the `ref.pos` numbers go down moving up in the data frame and up moving down in the colum. This would result in the following data frame:

```
   id ref.pos pos
1   1     298   1
2   1     299   2
3   1     300   3
4   1     301   4
5   1     302   5
6   1     303   6
7   1     800   7
8   1     801   8
9   1     802   9
10  1     803  10
11  1     804  11
12  2     500  30
13  2     501  31
14  2     502  32
15  2     503  33
16  2     504  34
17  2     505  35
```

**What I tried**
I wish I could provide some code here however I haven't figure out a proper way in two days, especially not something applicable to large datasets. I found `df %>% group_by(id) %>% tidyr::fill(ref.pos, .direction = "downup")` interesting however this repeats numbers rather than going down and up for me.

*I hope my question is clear, otherwise let me know in the comments!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `data.table`:

```
fillends <- function(x) nafill(nafill(x, "locf"), "nocb")

setDT(df)[, ref.pos2 := {
    dif <- fillends(c(diff(ref.pos), NA_integer_))
    frp <- fillends(ref.pos)
    fp <- fillends(replace(pos, is.na(ref.pos), NA_integer_))
    fifelse(is.na(ref.pos), frp + dif*(pos - fp), ref.pos)
}, id]
```

output:

```
    id ref.pos pos ref.pos2
 1:  1      NA   1      298
 2:  1      NA   2      299
 3:  1      NA   3      300
 4:  1     301   4      301
 5:  1     302   5      302
 6:  1     303   6      303
 7:  1     802   7      802
 8:  1     801   8      801
 9:  1      NA   9      800
10:  1      NA  10      799
11:  1      NA  11      798
12:  2     500  30      500
13:  2     501  31      501
14:  2     502  32      502
15:  2      NA  33      503
16:  2      NA  34      504
17:  2      NA  35      505
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(rep(1, 11), rep(2,6)),
    ref.pos = c(NA,NA,NA,301,302,303,802,801,NA,NA,NA, 500,501,502, NA, NA, NA),
    pos     = c(1:11, 30:35)
)
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer! I was just making an edit... see my comment to @ThomasIsCoding, but perhaps that is too much to add. Really appreciate the help, have spend two days on this already...

Comment: @CodeNoob, can you please add an example to your dataset? I have also edited my post based on my interpretation of your comment

Comment: WOW awesome, I can't thank you enough! I spent so much time on this already and need to get this wrapped up for a proposal but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option is to define custom function `fill`, which is applied in `ave`

```
fill <- function(v) {
  inds <- range(which(!is.na(v)))
  l <- 1:inds[1]
  u <- inds[2]:length(v)
  v[l] <- v[inds[1]] - rev(l)+1
  v[u] <- v[inds[2]] + seq_along(u)-1
  v
}

df <- within(df,ref.pos <- ave(ref.pos,id,FUN = fill))
```

such that

```
> df
   id ref.pos pos
1   1     298   1
2   1     299   2
3   1     300   3
4   1     301   4
5   1     302   5
6   1     303   6
7   1     800   7
8   1     801   8
9   1     802   9
10  1     803  10
11  1     804  11
12  2     500  30
13  2     501  31
14  2     502  32
15  2     503  33
16  2     504  34
17  2     505  35
```

Comment: I tested this on my large set and found out that I sometimes need to specify whether ref.pos numbers should go down moving up in the data frame or the opposite. Sorry I did not realize this as an option earlier! We can derive this from the value order in `v`, for example: `wo.na <- purrr::discard(v, is.na); direction <- wo.na[[1]] < wo.na[[2]]` which gives `TRUE` for the order you have now: `ref.pos` down when going up & up when going down, whereas when `FALSE` it should be down when going down & up when going up. I can also add this as a column to the `df` if that would be easier